# NLP and Clustering Words with Little Context Provided

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

My dataset has all user generated content for categorical variables. I'm trying to find a way to group these characteristics together. One column is "degree_type" where little context can be derived. The values for that column vary from "ba, mba, phd, degree, master of laws" and so on. Right now I'm using Levenshtein to measure these values against a set of values I've defined.

Would it be suggested to incorporate other columns? As in "subject" (computer science, history, etc.) and "institution" (stanford, harvard, etc.)? Please note these other columns suffer from the same problem as "degree_type".

I think there must be a better way to group these based on a clustering algorithm I'm not seeing? Any advice you'd like to share would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? It would be easyer to answer the question knowing more about the context.

Comment: Do you want to get these lables by clustering or use them as attributes to cluster? Can you give some example or scheme for what you want to do (e.g. what data you exactly have and what what you want to get)?